# Input devices randomly stop working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, touchscreen, input

I have a Lenovo all-in-one PC (IdeaCentre B520) with Windows 7 installed. It probably isn't old (systeminfo.exe shows Windows 7 installation from 2012 and BIOS from 2011). Its screen has touch input support.

There are three distinct symptoms of input failures, which usually occur at different times (but can occur simultaneously), which, I believe, may be connected:

1. Mouse input stops working and "device disconnect" sound is played, after a few seconds it starts working again (with "device connected" sound). Touch input and keyboard work fine during this (unless other mentioned symptoms occur). Mouse LED also works and doesn't seem to change its brightness. This happens regardless of USB port used with at least two different mice.
2. Mouse and touch input stop working. Mouse LED still works. The screen does not react at touch input at all. This is only fixed by reboot.
3. Bluetooth keyboard stops working. The state of its LEDs does not change. When I press a button on a *working* keyboard, Bluetooth icon LED on my PC blinks. It *still blinks* when this symptom occurs, but no application (including Windows itself) receives the input. This is only fixed by reboot.

There are no problems with USB ports when using e.g. USB flash drives, only with input devices. Indicator blinking on key press in symptom 3 suggests that Bluetooth connection is fine. So this is probably a software issue.

I haven't tried to move mouse via TeamViewer in symptom 2 yet, but I guess it won't work.

What is the way to prevent these problems from occuring in the future? Which Windows services (or BIOS options) should I investigate?

Is there a way to fix problems 2 or 3 without a full reboot?

**UPDATE**: Additional info collected. When I try to reboot the PC after issue #3 occurs, Windows *always* gets stuck (at least for a few hours) at shutdown screen and fails to shut down properly. Also, sometimes issue 1 does not fix itself, but re-plugging the mouse USB helps.

**UPDATE(2)**: I have tried to control mouse cursor with keyboard when issue #2 occurred. It worked. Unplugging this PC from the power socket for 10+ hours did not affect frequency or duration of mentioned issues.

**UPDATE(3)**: About a month ago I uninstalled one of the Windows updates which has been reported to cause input device issues. It was claimed that subsequent Windows updates (which I have installed) should fix the issue caused by it, however, during the past month my keyboard disconnected only once, in comparison to 1+ disconnects per day that had been occuring earlier. I also ran `sfc /scannow` and changed the mouse I use immediately after uninstalling that update, which could have helped to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A user in the Lenovo forums said unplugging the computer from the power outlet, as opposed to just shutting down, was helpful to their mouse/input problems.

I would also try resetting your BIOS values to the defaults, but write down the current settings first, just in case!

Be sure you are using the latest drivers from the Manufacturer and/or Windows update. For bluetooth issues, try disabling the on-board bluetooth and purchasing an external bluetooth USB adapter.

The mouse and touchscreen issues are probably related as you suspect. Often touch input uses a USB type interface to the other components.

Your update about issue#3 is concerning. Windows shutdown issues can be complex.

To thoroughly troubleshoot, reinstall windows (after data backup) and also run hardware diagnostics from mfgr.  If USB issues continue, a component of the motherboard may be defective. :-(

Comment: Thank your for the answer, I will try troubleshooting methods you suggested. It may take some time, though.